# How to change the directory for rostest log files?

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
my question is if it is possible to change the directory
where rostest saves the test results and if so how it is
done. The intention behind this is that I want an automated
testing system embedded into jenkins. Right now, rostest
saves to a hidden directory in my home directory but as
jenkins is an online tool and my project is distributed
I want the results to be saved on my server.

Some additional information:
I have ros fuerte running on my PC (and on the
server too, but I'm not sure since I am not
the owner...).

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72988/how-to-change-the-directory-for-rostest-log-files?/) by [MaxDai](https://answers.ros.org/users/5953/maxdai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several [environment variables available](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#System_Data_Environment_Variables) in particular ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR looks like it's what you want.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0